# How to make sure file is closed in C program with exit() used

Tags: c, memory-management

I am maintaining c project where the program can be simplified as follows:

```
int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {  
  initVM();
  // global pointer to a file where all output of
  // the program are directed to
  debugOut = fopen(DEBUG_OUTPUT_FILE_PATH, "wt");

  if (argc == 2) runFile(argv[1]); // may call `exit`
  else if (argc == 1) repl();      // may call `exit`
  else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: clox [path]\n");
    exit(64);
  }

  fclose(debugOut);
  freeVM();
  return 0;
}
```

The question is: what if `exit` function was called before `fclose`, will the file be closed?

I think the answer is no, if so, how to make sure the file is closed? define my own exit function and use it whenever I need to terminate the program?

Alas, there is no finally statement in c. Or there is?

Since I haven't mastered c yet, I went online searching for what `exit` function does or finally statement equivalents in c. I came here to post the question and I am still searching for it.

Comment: Closing the progam from `return` in `main()`, or from `exit()` flushes and closes all open file streams. Calling `exit(42)` is identical to `return 42;` from `main()`.

Comment: Note that C has an [`atexit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/atexit?view=msvc-170) function.

Comment: Recognising that you've only shown a snippet, a better solution would be to check argc BEFORE doing anything else (like opening a file). If the program cannot run, don't waste time doing things that need to be cleaned up. (PS: always validate that `fopen()` succeeded.)

Comment: @Fe2O3 yeah true. My code can be optimized to handle those cases. However, I want to note that there are more than one call to exit function in the program deep in the code. What I am looking for is knowledge and best practice. I also admire your name and chemistery as a whole!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the file will be closed. Any open file descriptors are closed automatically when **exit** is used in C. However, it is good practice to close the file descriptors yourself, so you can check that they have been closed successfully.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO C standard states that open streams will be closed.

##### C23 §7.24.4.4 The exit function

> The exit function causes normal program termination to occur. No functions registered by the **at_quick_exit** function are called. If a program calls the **exit** function more than once, or calls the **quick_exit** function in addition to the exit function, the behavior is undefined.

> First, all functions registered by the **atexit** function are called, in the reverse order of their registration, except that a function is called after any previously registered functions that had already been called at the time it was registered. If, during the call to any such function, a call to the **longjmp** function is made that would terminate the call to the registered function, the behavior is undefined.

> Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all open streams are closed, and all files created by the **tmpfile** function are removed.

> Finally, control is returned to the host environment. If the value of *status* is zero or **EXIT_SUCCESS**, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned. If the value of *status* is **EXIT_FAILURE**, an implementation-defined form of the status unsuccessful termination is returned. Otherwise the status returned is implementation-defined.

From this description we also learn about the [`atexit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/atexit) function, which can be used to register functions to be called upon normal program termination (calling `exit` or returning from `main`).

You may also consider restructuring your code so that the correctness of the program arguments is validated before opening any streams.